# Linking updated assets in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create a chain which holds a document.
I have created the asset in the model file as

```
asset document identified by documentid {
  o String documentid
  o String formImageBase64 //will use IPFS Later
  o String nameOfSignator
  o String addressOfSignator
  o Integer ageOfSignator
  o Boolean isSigned
  o DateTime dateTimeOfSigning
}
```

And there are multiple documents containing information of different people.

If the document is updated(new asset is created), How to show a link between the old document and the updated document.

Update
Changing Title from "Creating Application Form using Hyperledger Composer"
To "Chaining/Connecting updated assets in Hyperledger Composer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the New Updating document, I added a new string which contains the unique "document of the previous string. Making it kind of a singly linked list.

```
asset document identified by documentid {
  o String documentID
  o String previousDocumentID // optional(later) original document "0" for now
  o String formImageBase64 //will use IPFS Later
  o String nameOfSignator
  o String addressOfSignator
  o Integer ageOfSignator
  o Boolean isSigned
  o DateTime dateTimeOfSigning
}
```

This way I can chain documents together.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type of relation you want to show between the past documents and the new documents but if you want to show the historical information of the transactions then you can use [HistorianRecord](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/reference/historian.html)

Comment: Think of it as updating the current document which needs to be resigned by a client. Now then client needs both the past and updated document for approval(Consent).

Comment: Its like creating a new draft of the document. 
I just added a new String which points to the "documentid" of the previous document. that way I can easily know what was the previous document.